# Deserialize JSON not giving expected result

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am sending a json string to a .cshtml page using `var x1 = Request["jsonData"];`

the json file is urlEncoded in javascript from the previous page and looks like this.

```
var x1 = Request["jsonData"];
//var x2 = "%5B%7B%22Author%22%3A%22John%20andeberg%22%2C%22ClosedDate%22%3Anull%2C%22Comment%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ComVal%22%3A2%2C%22CreatedDate%22%3A%222012-05-04T14%3A32%3A00%22%2C%22Description%22%3A%22testing%22%2C%22DType%22%3Anull%2C%22DueDate%22%3A%222012-07-17T00%3A00%3A00%22%2C%22ID%22%3A30%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Meet%20with%20technical%20teams%20to%20discuss%20solution%22%2C%22OtherID%22%3Anull%2C%22PercentComplete%22%3A0%2C%22Priority%22%3A141%2C%22PriorityName%22%3A%22Urgent%22%2C%22ProjectRef%22%3A43%2C%22ResID%22%3A1%2C%22ResName%22%3A%22John%20Vandeberg%22%2C%22Responsible%22%3A%22John%20Vandeberg%22%2C%22Status%22%3A138%2C%22StatusName%22%3A%22Open%22%2C%22UpdateBy%22%3A%22John%20Vandeberg%22%2C%22UpdateDate%22%3A%222013-06-10T11%3A08%3A00%22%7D%5D";
x2 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(x1);
```

So the string is decoded HttpUtility.UrlDecode(x1) which gives.

```
    "[{\"Author\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"ClosedDate\":null,\"Comment\":\"\",\"ComVal\":3,\"CreatedDate\":\"2012-05-04T14:32:00\",\"Description\":\"\",\"DType\":null,\"DueDate\":\"2012-06-20T00:00:00\",\"ID\":29,\"Name\":\"Review the detailed project management plan\",\"OtherID\":null,\"PercentComplete\":0,\"Priority\":142,\"PriorityName\":\"High\",\"ProjectRef\":43,\"ResID\":null,\"ResName\":null,\"Responsible\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"Status\":138,\"StatusName\":\"Open\",\"UpdateBy\":null,\"UpdateDate\":null},{\"Author\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"ClosedDate\":null,\"Comment\":\"\",\"ComVal\":1,\"CreatedDate\":\"2012-05-04T14:33:00\",\"Description\":\"Add Description\",\"DType\":null,\"DueDate\":\"2013-06-28T00:00:00\",\"ID\":31,\"Name\":\"Discuss recruitment with HR for required BA's\",\"OtherID\":null,\"PercentComplete\":0,\"Priority\":142,\"PriorityName\":\"High\",\"ProjectRef\":43,\"ResID\":null,\"ResName\":null,\"Responsible\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"Status\":138,\"StatusName\":\"Open\",\"UpdateBy\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"UpdateDate\":\"2012-05-07T21:25:00\"},{\"Author\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"ClosedDate\":null,\"Comment\":\"Test1\",\"ComVal\":1,\"CreatedDate\":\"2012-03-26T10:37:00\",\"Description\":\"PO Approved\",\"DType\":null,\"DueDate\":\"2013-06-28T00:00:00\",\"ID\":20,\"Name\":\"Get standard documentation from PMO 1\",\"OtherID\":null,\"PercentComplete\":2,\"Priority\":142,\"PriorityName\":\"High\",\"ProjectRef\":43,\"ResID\":null,\"ResName\":null,\"Responsible\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"Status\":138,\"StatusName\":\"Open\",\"UpdateBy\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"UpdateDate\":\"2012-04-07T23:29:00\"},{\"Author\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"ClosedDate\":null,\"Comment\":\"\",\"ComVal\":1,\"CreatedDate\":\"2012-05-04T14:30:00\",\"Description\":\"\",\"DType\":null,\"DueDate\":\"2013-06-28T00:00:00\",\"ID\":27,\"Name\":\"Schedule meeting with senior stakeholders for scope clarification\",\"OtherID\":null,\"PercentComplete\":0,\"Priority\":142,\"PriorityName\":\"High\",\"ProjectRef\":43,\"ResID\":null,\"ResName\":null,\"Responsible\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"Status\":138,\"StatusName\":\"Open\",\"UpdateBy\":null,\"UpdateDate\":null},{\"Author\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"ClosedDate\":null,\"Comment\":\"\",\"ComVal\":2,\"CreatedDate\":\"2012-05-04T14:31:00\",\"Description\":\"\",\"DType\":null,\"DueDate\":\"2013-07-31T00:00:00\",\"ID\":28,\"Name\":\"Review previous PCB minutes and provide feedback\",\"OtherID\":null,\"PercentComplete\":0,\"Priority\":142,\"PriorityName\":\"High\",\"ProjectRef\":43,\"ResID\":null,\"ResName\":null,\"Responsible\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"Status\":138,\"StatusName\":\"Open\",\"UpdateBy\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"UpdateDate\":\"2013-09-27T21:10:00\"}]";
```

`x2 = x2.Replace("\\", string.Empty);`   (I try to replace the escape characters using this function, but it does nothing)   `x2.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);` does nothing either.

I then put the result into a dynamic array

```
dynamic jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x);
```

but this give a weird output.

```
JArray

[0] = JObject
    [0] = JProperty
        [0] = JValue John Vandeberg
    [1] = JProperty
        [0] = JValue
    [2] = JProperty
        [0] = JValue
    [3] = JProperty
        [0] = JValue 3
    [4] = JProperty
        [0] = JValue 4/05/2012 2:32:00 PM
```

**Question:** Why cant I clear the \" escape characters as I think this is the reason the Deserialize is not giving the expect output which should include the item names.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should better create a `class` of `Object` that you want for better usage for example with your `Object` like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ClosedDate { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int ComVal { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string OtherID {get;set;}
    public float PercentComplete {get;set;}
    public int Priority {get;set;}
    public string PriorityName {get;set;}
    public int ProjectRef {get;set;}
    public string ResID {get;set;}
    public string ResName {get;set;}
    public string Responsible {get;set;}
    public int Status {get;set;}
    public string StatusName {get;set;}
    public string UpdateBy {get;set;}
    public DateTime? UpdateDate {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can then `Deserialize` it to your known `Object` with `JavaScriptSerializer` like this

```
string json = "[{\"Author\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"ClosedDate\":null,\"Comment\":\"\",\"ComVal\":3,\"CreatedDate\":\"2012-05-04T14:32:00\",\"Description\":\"\",\"DType\":null,\"DueDate\":\"2012-06-20T00:00:00\",\"ID\":29,\"Name\":\"Review the detailed project management plan\",\"OtherID\":null,\"PercentComplete\":0,\"Priority\":142,\"PriorityName\":\"High\",\"ProjectRef\":43,\"ResID\":null,\"ResName\":null,\"Responsible\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"Status\":138,\"StatusName\":\"Open\",\"UpdateBy\":null,\"UpdateDate\":null},{\"Author\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"ClosedDate\":null,\"Comment\":\"\",\"ComVal\":1,\"CreatedDate\":\"2012-05-04T14:33:00\",\"Description\":\"Add Description\",\"DType\":null,\"DueDate\":\"2013-06-28T00:00:00\",\"ID\":31,\"Name\":\"Discuss recruitment with HR for required BA's\",\"OtherID\":null,\"PercentComplete\":0,\"Priority\":142,\"PriorityName\":\"High\",\"ProjectRef\":43,\"ResID\":null,\"ResName\":null,\"Responsible\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"Status\":138,\"StatusName\":\"Open\",\"UpdateBy\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"UpdateDate\":\"2012-05-07T21:25:00\"},{\"Author\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"ClosedDate\":null,\"Comment\":\"Test1\",\"ComVal\":1,\"CreatedDate\":\"2012-03-26T10:37:00\",\"Description\":\"PO Approved\",\"DType\":null,\"DueDate\":\"2013-06-28T00:00:00\",\"ID\":20,\"Name\":\"Get standard documentation from PMO 1\",\"OtherID\":null,\"PercentComplete\":2,\"Priority\":142,\"PriorityName\":\"High\",\"ProjectRef\":43,\"ResID\":null,\"ResName\":null,\"Responsible\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"Status\":138,\"StatusName\":\"Open\",\"UpdateBy\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"UpdateDate\":\"2012-04-07T23:29:00\"},{\"Author\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"ClosedDate\":null,\"Comment\":\"\",\"ComVal\":1,\"CreatedDate\":\"2012-05-04T14:30:00\",\"Description\":\"\",\"DType\":null,\"DueDate\":\"2013-06-28T00:00:00\",\"ID\":27,\"Name\":\"Schedule meeting with senior stakeholders for scope clarification\",\"OtherID\":null,\"PercentComplete\":0,\"Priority\":142,\"PriorityName\":\"High\",\"ProjectRef\":43,\"ResID\":null,\"ResName\":null,\"Responsible\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"Status\":138,\"StatusName\":\"Open\",\"UpdateBy\":null,\"UpdateDate\":null},{\"Author\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"ClosedDate\":null,\"Comment\":\"\",\"ComVal\":2,\"CreatedDate\":\"2012-05-04T14:31:00\",\"Description\":\"\",\"DType\":null,\"DueDate\":\"2013-07-31T00:00:00\",\"ID\":28,\"Name\":\"Review previous PCB minutes and provide feedback\",\"OtherID\":null,\"PercentComplete\":0,\"Priority\":142,\"PriorityName\":\"High\",\"ProjectRef\":43,\"ResID\":null,\"ResName\":null,\"Responsible\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"Status\":138,\"StatusName\":\"Open\",\"UpdateBy\":\"John  Vandeberg\",\"UpdateDate\":\"2013-09-27T21:10:00\"}]";

var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Book>>(json);
```

Note here `Deserialize<List<Book>>`, this will `Deserialize` your `JSON` to a known `Object Type` which is `List<Book>`

- `List<T>` because your `JSON` returning multiple `Object`
- `Book` because it's the class name of the `Object`

then if you need to use the `Author` from the `result`, you can use this

```
string Author = result[i].Author; // i > the index in the list (with your JSON, it's 0 - 4 because you have 5 results
```

also note in the `Object` declaration for `ClosedDate`, it's written as `public DateTime? ClosedDate { get; set; }`, it's because you return the value `null` for it so you need to add `?` to accept `null` value for type `DateTime`

Comment: @Anil - your answer is also correct I was able to get is working using the following var jsonData = Json.Decode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request["jsonData"]));

Comment: @ Kyo - your answer was very comprehensive and solved the issue perfectly.    this is the end code I used var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Book>>(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request["jsonData"]));   - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Escape characters are part of the C# syntax and they can't be replaced using "Replace" function. Escape character's purpose is to start character sequences which have to be interpreted differently from the same characters occurring without the prefixed escape character.

Don't perform the replace operation on the decoded JSON string.

if you are ok with System.Web.Helpers (MVCApplication Solution Path\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Helpers.dll) assembly then use JSON.Decode method to deserialize the JSON Object.